# Magento 2: I need to add a field to order form that will allow us to manually enter a shipping amount?

Tags: magento2

Need to add a field to order form that will allow us to manually enter a shipping amount?

[image]

Any idea?
Thanks

Comment: Hi Shomita, have you done that functionality ?

Comment: Yes i have done this funtionality

Comment: Great, can you please share this functionality